# Setting different font colors for characters in a cell based on character position

Tags: fonts, colors, macros

I am trying to set three different colors for first 3, second 3 and last 3 characters of contents of all the cells in a range. The below code is changing the entire cell content to green, not only the first 3 characters.

Please guide me how to do this. I am very new to VB.

```
Sub LoopAndChangeColor()

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim targetRange As Range
  'Set targetRange = Range("A1:A10")

  'For Each cell In targetRange
  For i = 1 To 10
    Cells(i, 1).Characters(1, 3).Font.Color = vbGreen
    Cells(i, 1).Characters(4, 3).Font.Color = vbBlue
    Cells(i, 1).Characters(7, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I did a good search to identify if this fix is already suggested in this site. Since I couldn't find any, I have posted this question. Kindly advise if such a solution is already offered. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This info may be too late, but the macro to do what you need is ready to use. Visit: http://excelfindandformat.herobo.com and the related 34 youtube videos.